# firefox 35.0.1: svg mask animation doesn't work

Tags: firefox, animation, svg, mask, snap.svg

after my firefox update to version 35.0.1 my svg animations doesn't work in firefox, but it was working in previous versions and it still works in firefox beta (36), nightly (37.0a2) and other browsers (opera, chrome, safari, modern ie):

html:

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="logo-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="55px" height="53.758px" viewBox="-1061.986 3038.43 55 53.758" enable-background="new -1061.986 3038.43 188.279 53.758" xml:space="preserve">
                        <g id="logo-mask" >
                            <rect id="sygnet" fill="#FFFFFF" x="-1100" y="3038" width="100" height="50"/>
                        </g>
                        <g id="logo-black">
                            <rect id="sygnet" fill="#000000" x="-1100" y="3038" width="100" height="50"/>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
<div id="button">Click me!</div>
```

css:

```
    body{
    background-color: #777777;
}

#button{
    margin-right: 100px;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

js (using snap.svg):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var s = Snap(),
        svg = Snap.select('#logo-svg'),
        logo = Snap.select('#logo-mask'),
        logoBlack = Snap.select('#logo-black'),
        mask = svg.rect(-1100, 2830, 280, 100).attr({
            fill: 'white',
            id: 'maska-logo'
        });
    logoBlack.attr({'mask': mask, 'opacity': 1});
});

$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){
    var maska = Snap.select('#maska-logo');
    maska.animate({
        transform: 'T'+[0,200]
    }, 500);

});
```

simple example:    `http://jsfiddle.net/7yq14L0f/2/`

any idea, why? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by a change in the Firefox code which was not completely correct and which was then fixed. Bug [932771](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=932771) caused it and bug [1127507](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1127507) which was backported as far as Firefox 36 fixed it.